# What is the "spectral representation of unitary operators"?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

It's in Nagy's book "Harmonic Analysis of Operators on Hilbert space" on page 31, the proof of the von Neumann inequality for polynomials.

What is the "spectral representation of unitary operators"? And why does it imply that $\| p (U) \|$ is equal to maximum of $| p(\lambda) |$ on the spectrum of $U$ (where $U$ is a unitary operator, and $p$ a polynomial of degree $n$)?

I tried to find more about this, but couldn't.

Comment: There is no need to apply the spectral theorem. Every unitary operator is normal, i.e. it commutes with its adjoint. For a normal operator $T$ and a polynomial $p$ the operator $p(T)$  is normal as well. It is known that for a normal operator $S$ we have $\|S\|=r(S),$ where $r(S)$ denotes the spectral radius of $S.$ On the other hand $\sigma(p(T))=p(\sigma(T)).$ Hence $$\|p(T)\|=\sup \{|p(z)|\,:\, z\in \sigma(T)\}$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But **why** is $p(T)$ normal as well?

Comment: If two normal operators $A$ and $B$ commute than $AB$ and $A+B$ are normal. Thus $T^n$ is normal for any $n.$ Hence $p(T)$ is normal as a linear combination of normal commuting operators.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Interesting, I thought it was a little harder to show this. But let's say I have a function $f$ from the disk algebra. Can I apply this logic here too? Because as $f$ is from the disk algebra, it can be represented in the form of a power series, which partial sums are polynomials? 

I am just confused because my Professor told me that - at least for the disk algebra functions - I need to use the spectral theorem (całka spektralna) and a construction from the continuous functional calculus (korzystać z konstrukcji "ciągłego rachunku funkcyjnego")

Comment: How come you are citing Polish terms ? You can directly apply to $U$ any continuous function on $\mathbb{T},$ the disk functions in particular. By the Weierstrass theorem any function $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ is a uniform limit of trigonometric polynomials of the form $p(z)=\sum_{ -N}^Na_kz^k $ for $|z|=1.$ We have $p(U)=\sum_{ -N}^Na_kU^k.$ Then if  a sequence $p_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ then $p_n(U)\to f(U).$ It can be shown that the limit does not depend on the  approximating sequence $p_n$ but on $f,$ only.

Comment: If you can read in Polish see chapter 5 http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~szwarc/pdf/anfun2007/analiza-funkcjonalna2p.pdf

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc It's because I am Polish, I'm just citing the Polish terms because I don't know the proper English translation for them. Thanks for your PDF, it really seems way easier than I expected.